# java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: getPosition is not implemented by this StateStore

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

```
NAjava.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: getPosition is not implemented by this StateStore 
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.StateStore.getPosition(StateStore.java:165)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.ChangeLoggingKeyValueBytesStore.log(ChangeLoggingKeyValueBytesStore.java:142)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.ChangeLoggingKeyValueBytesStore.put(ChangeLoggingKeyValueBytesStore.java:79)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.ChangeLoggingKeyValueBytesStore.put(ChangeLoggingKeyValueBytesStore.java:33)
```

Please let us know the alternative for this method in Kafka

```
@Evolving
    default Position getPosition() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException(
            "getPosition is not implemented by this StateStore (" + getClass() + ")"
        );
    }
```

This is code snippet which is throwing the exception.
https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/3.2.3/streams/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/streams/processor/StateStore.java

Comment: What kind of StateStore is it? How did you create it?  (also the logs are supposed to display the name ("... by this StateStore (xxx)"), did you remove it?)

Comment: This is called from MeteredKeyValueStore of Kafka . I am creating state store using below method (org.apache.kafka.streams.state)                                                                                                                        Stores.keyValueStoreBuilder(,,,)

Comment: What's the value of the `supplier` parameter when you call `Stores.keyValueStoreBuilder(...)` ?

Comment: I am passing the instance of StateStoreClass.

Comment: https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/3.2.3/streams/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/streams/processor/StateStore.java. Its is thrown from this class of kafka. Is there any alternative way to solve this error ?